# Where lookup tables should be placed in a microservices architecture?

Tags: microservices, lookup-tables

In a microservices architecture, each microservice has its own database and tables should not be duplicated in different databases.
But there are tables, like lookup tables (called also reference tables), that are needed by multiple microservices.
Should we put lookup tables in each microservice database, or is it better to create a new microservice with a database holding all the lookup tables ?

Comment: In each service, storage permitting.

Comment: What dou you mean by storage permitting ?

Comment: If you store the same data multiple times it will take up storage.

Answer (score 1):

Lookup tables will usually contain read only data (they are like view models), so they can be available across the system in whatever technical solution you choose.

A shared read only database table, a distributed cache, on a CDN...

Make sense?

Comment: Yes you are right. But i'm asking about the best practice to deal with lookup tables in micro-services environment.